# Overlay two images in a responsive environment

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

I'd like to see if there is a way to overlay a sale tag onto a div. Also, I want to make sure that it responds in a responsive environment. I've tried position:absolute but I'll have to create numerous media query break points in order to do this.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="category-item">
        <div class="sale-tag">
        <img src="/sale-tag.png"></div>
        <div class="item-image">
            <a href="xxxx"><img src="xxxx.jpg" alt="xxxx" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-details">
            <h5><a href="xxxx">
                <h4>XXXX</h4>
                XXXX</a></h5>
            <hr class="product-item">
            <div class="item-price">$XX.00</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.category-item {
    min-height: 290px;
    height: auto;
    max-height:none;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    background-color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    border-radius:2px;
}
.sale-tag {
    position:absolute;
    left:16px;
    top:16px;
    z-index:23;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.category-item` should have `position: relative;` for this to work.

I've made a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Would this fit your needs.

```
<img style="background:url(image.jpg)" src="overlay_image.gif" alt="xxxx" class="img-responsive" />
```